# How to read a Text file from server and store to a separate variable?

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm, web-server

I am working on reading a text file from the server, using http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/GSMClientConnected. It gives me this code:

```
char path[]="/asciilogo.txt"
```

I want to store only the contents that are inside the text file to a variable (String). But `client.read();` only reads a single character at a time. Also, it takes all the HTTP, GET, TIME parameters together.

How to store only the contents that are present in the text file to a string variable?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I found:

You need to have a special character like  "*" (a delimiter), from which important data will flow through.

```
char z = '*';
int s=0;

void setup()
{ 
  // usual initialization  
} 

void loop()
{
  if (client.available())  
  {
    char c = client.read();
    // Serial.print(c);
    if (z == c)
    {
      s=1;
    }

  if(s == 1)
  {
    int i=0;
    k[i] = c;
    i=i+1;
    // Serial.print(k);
  }

  place +=k;

  Serial.print(place);

  }

.......
}
```

Comment: that'll work but you have to declare `i` outside of the `loop()` because the way it is now, it'll always be 0.